# Convert geometry to latitude-longitude using PostGIS ST_Transform

Tags: postgis, coordinates, coordinate-system

My table has a geometric field, in EPSG:3857, of type point. I need the latitude and longitude, in EPSG: 4326, of each point.  Could someone give me a valid example of how to use ST_Transform().

Comment: Please state the SRS or CRS of the geometry -- it matters.

Comment: My geometry is in EPSG:3857. I did not think it mattered ... if I want to get the coordinates of my geometry in the EPSG: 4326 as I do?

Answer (score 20):

From [the PostGIS docs](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Transform.html),

> ST_Transform — Returns a *new* geometry with its coordinates transformed to the SRID referenced by the integer parameter.

```
geometry ST_Transform (geometry g, integer srid);
```

So, to read *transformed* points

```
SELECT ST_AsText (ST_Transform (geom, 4326)) FROM table ...
```

If you want long and lat as separate fields

```
SELECT ST_X (ST_Transform (geom, 4326)) AS long,
       ST_Y (ST_Transform (geom, 4326)) AS lat
FROM table ...
```

Comment: That is also based on an assumption: that PostGIS knows what the existing SRID is. See ST_SRID(), Find_SRID(), UpdateGeometrySRID(), etc, if unsure. Or ask for clarification here, and i'll expand my answer for you.

Comment: The link above should be this one https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Transform.html (domain is postgis.net)

Comment: @MiroJ. .. Corrected, thanks

Answer (score 6):

Try this below. ST_AsText returns the well-known text.  ST_X and ST_Y return the actual  longitude and latitude (assuming geom is in the appropriate SRS).

```
SELECT ST_AsText(geom), ST_X(geom), ST_Y(geom) FROM table
```

Comment: That will work *if* the existing geom is already in a long-lat SRS. Otherwise it will produce easting-northing coords.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1**

Set `SRID` to your table:

```
SELECT UpdateGeometrySRID('Table Name' , 'the_geom' ,32645)
```

**Step 2**

```
SELECT *,
ST_X(ST_Transform (the_geom, 4326)) AS "Longitude",
ST_Y(ST_Transform (the_geom, 4326)) AS "Latitude"
FROM "Table Name"
```

Answer (score -3):

These st_x/st_y functions are confusing. I am working with PostGresQL/PostGIS 2.4 as we speak. This is the bounding rect roughly enclosing the country of Kenya:

```
    bounds.northeast = new LatLng(4.959918, 41.012352);
    bounds.southwest = new LatLng(-1.603490, 33.849266);
```

Converting one of the points into a geometry object, then use st_x() = 4.95... st_y()=41.012... If you use google maps, x is latitude and y is longitude !