# Getting meters from pgr_dijkstra

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting, php, osm2po

I imported http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/germany/baden-wuerttemberg.html into my PostgreSQL database which supports PostGIS.
Now I wrote a PHP script which gets two points (lon, lat, which are currently hardcoded) and should calculate the distance between them with for example the Dijkstra-algorithm.

```
<?PHP
// Database connection settings
   define("PG_DB"  , "routing");
   define("PG_HOST", "localhost"); 
   define("PG_USER", "postgres");
   define("PG_PORT", "5432"); 
   define("PG_PASSWORD", "****");
   define("TABLE",   "bw_2po_4pgr");
   
   
   $lonlat = array(9.1829321, 48.7758459);
   $startEdge = findNearestEdge($lonlat);
   
   $lonlat = array(9.138027, 48.6408189);
   $endEdge = findNearestEdge($lonlat);
   
  
   function findNearestEdge($lonlat) {
   $con = pg_connect("dbname=".PG_DB." host=".PG_HOST." user=".PG_USER." password=".PG_PASSWORD);
   
   $sql = "SELECT id, source, target, geom_way, ST_distance(geom_way, ST_GeometryFromText(
   'POINT(".$lonlat[0]." ".$lonlat[1].")', 4326)) AS dist 
   FROM ".TABLE."
   WHERE geom_way && ST_setsrid(
   'BOX3D(".($lonlat[0]-0.1)."
          ".($lonlat[1]-0.1).",
          ".($lonlat[0]+0.1)."
          ".($lonlat[1]+0.1).")'::box3d, 4326)
    ORDER BY dist LIMIT 1";
   
   $query = pg_query($con, $sql);
   
   $edge['id'] = pg_fetch_result($query, 0, 0);
   $edge['source'] = pg_fetch_result($query, 0, 1);
   $edge['target'] = pg_fetch_result($query, 0, 2);
   $edge['geom_way'] = pg_fetch_result($query, 0, 3);
   
   pg_close($con);
  
   
   print_r($edge);
   return $edge;
   
   }
    
   $con = pg_connect("dbname=".PG_DB." host=".PG_HOST." user=".PG_USER." password=".PG_PASSWORD);
   
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM pgr_dijkstra(
            'SELECT id, source, target, cost, reverse_cost
            FROM ".TABLE."',
            ".$startEdge['source'].",
            ".$endEdge['target'].",
            directed := true);";
                    
    $query = pg_query($con, $sql);
    
   while($res = pg_fetch_assoc($query)) {
       $sum = $res['agg_cost'];
   }
   
   echo "\r\n";
   echo $sum;
    
    
   pg_close($con);
```

This is my result when I call the PHP script from the browser.

```
Array ( [id] => 295007 [source] => 123354 [target] => 33187 [geom_way] => 0102000020E6100000040000000DE36E10AD5D22400512B98553634840ADDA3521AD5D22406127ABD84E634840EE395563AE5D22402D2059654B6348403E48AA4AB65D2240825E6EE646634840 ) 
Array ( [id] => 164375 [source] => 162839 [target] => 162822 [geom_way] => 0102000020E6100000030000000E791563AA46224086274FB4065248406F905A722647224054049376FE514840E129E44A3D472240FBECDBA4FD514840 ) 
0.3859884999999998
```

The last value of my result should be the agg_cost. But here I do not know what unit measurement is this and how I can get meter/kilometer out of that?

I controlled that my route is correct with QGIS and Google Maps. Both Routes look quite similar here, so somehow I should get the right distance between my two points?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Can someone help me here?

Comment: You need a projection from lat, lon into plane coordinates. Postgis can so that transformation for you, https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/95373/convert-geometry-to-latitude-longitude-using-postgis-st-transform

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unit is *degree*, as you seem to have geometries referenced in EPSG:4326, and the edge length as `cost`.

If so, two options

- if your `cost` attribute is the plain length of each edge (*shortest path*), use a cast to `GEOGRAPHY` instead, either in a pre-processing step to update the `cost` and `reverse_cost` columns, or directly in the `edge_query` passed to `pgr_Dijkstra()`, i.e. `ST_Length(geom::GEOGRAPHY)`; the `agg_cost` will then be a measure in *meter*
- if your cost is a different measure, aggregate the `ST_Length(geom::GEOGRAPHY)` of all edges you joined back to the `pgr_Dijkstra()` result set; again, the sum is the total distance in *meter*

**Note** that you will have to pass in the same value for `reverse_cost`!

More on the two different spatial types:

- [Is the Geometry(4326) an alias for Geography datatype?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/367366/is-the-geometry4326-an-alias-for-geography-datatype/367374#367374)

**Update:**

I don't know much about *osm2po*, as it is hard to find information about it, but it creates a `km` column that likely denotes the edge length.

You can simply use that as your cost columns; replace `cost` and `reverse_cost` with `km` in the `edge_sql` string, and the `agg_cost` will be in `km`.

---

Check on spatial *(K)NN* searches to find closest edges to given locations more efficiently; some of my own answers, covering the overall concept and some notes about precision and units:

- [Efficient way to find nearest feature between huge postgres tables](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/297208/efficient-way-to-find-nearest-feature-between-huge-postgres-tables/297244#297244)
- [Get barrier edge id](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/283794/get-barrier-edge-id/283797#283797)
- [Find closest polygon from point and get its attributes?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/338312/find-closest-polygon-from-point-and-get-its-attributes/338328#338328)
- [How to UPDATE with LATERAL Nearest-Neighbour query?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/278357/how-to-update-with-lateral-nearest-neighbour-query/278362#278362)

Comment: How can I found out in which measure my costs are? Where exactly should I do the ST_Length(geom::GEOGRAPHY) and geom should be my geography value? 
I tried this in pgr_dijkstra() with the cost value and it says that it can not convert a double precision to geography.
Can you maybe give an exact example? I am a bit confused with this stuff, because it is all kind of new for me.

Comment: I edited the tag 'osm2po' since it wasn't really related to the question, but it may be after all. It seems that, if you want to know *anything* about that tool, you will have to contact the author. Nevertheless, it seems also that it creates a `km` column in the table, which you could use instead of the `cost` column. See updated answer.

Comment: I edited my post and add an overview of the database. 
Yesterday I tried it already with the `km` column instead of the `cost` column, but it did not work out --> gave me not the right answer.

Comment: Seeing your added image: the`geom_way` column is defined as `GEOMETRY(LINESTRING, 4326)`, so the `cost` units are likely a *degree* value, since EPSG:4326 is a geographic CRS. If you wanted to use the type conversion, you will have to replace both `cost` and `reverse_cost` in the `edge_sql` with `ST_Length(geom_way::GEOGRAPHY) AS cost/reverse_cost`.

Comment: `SELECT id, source, target, ST_Length(geom_way::GEOGRAPHY) AS cost, ST_LENGTH(geom_way::GEOGRAPHY) AS reverse_cost`

I changed this one in pgr_dijkstra now and got this `agg_cost = 17644.794232367145` which stands for 17,6km. How can Google Maps give me 24,3km on the same route?
Do you think the values of the OSM data are wrong or the import with Osm2po went wrong or you have some other idea?